# How to cancel a pending request in an inner HTTP observable with RXJS?

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, observable, rxjs-pipeable-operators

**Cancelling a pending HTTP request when changing the page**

We have an Angular service that has an expensive HTTP query that 3 different consumers can access. Each consumer can modify this query at any point, make a new request, and all other consumers must be updated with the new data.

Because HTTP subscriptions close immediately on completion, we used the inner observable pattern with behavior subjects to keep the consumers connected (see below).

The problem then, is when the user changes the page, there's no way for the current pending HTTP response to get cancelled.

Normally I don't think it would be too much of an issue to throw away an HTTP request in the background...but beyond it being an expensive operation, I have discovered if the pending response is indeed resolved after the user has returned back to the page, it'll update the consumers with data for an older query.

No bueno.

#### Service call

```
private dataSubject = new BehaviorSubject<MyData>(...);
public data$ = this.dataSubject.asObservable();
...

getData(): Observable<MyData> {
  if (this.dataSubject)
    return this.data$;
  } else {
    const http$ = this.http.post(...))
      .pipe(map(response => response as MyData),
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)); // see tearDown() below
    http$.subscribe(
      (availableDevices: MyData) => {
        this.dataSubject.next(availableDevices);
      }
    );
    return this.data$;
  }
}
```

I attempted to create a tear down method in the service that each consumer calls during it's ngDestroy(), but it did not work unless I completed the stream. But at that point, I wasn't unable to restart the stream again when the user returns to the page.

```
tearDown(): void {
  this.unsubscribe$.next();
  this.unsubscribe$.complete();
  // this.dataSubject.next(null);
  // this.dataSubject.complete(); -- breaks
}
```

I'm by no mean an RXJS expert, so feel free to point out if my overall design is wrong. I have a nagging suspicion that I should be using **switchMap()** or **share** to prevent two consumers making the same request; but because this observable pattern is semi-hot, I'm not sure what the right course of action is.  Let alone when it comes to cancelling it.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, so since you have the behaviorSubject you should actually use it. Instead of returning this.data$ you should be pushing the returned data into the behaviorSubject using this.dataSubject.next(apiData). Then the 3 consumers subscribe to the public data$, assuming they are all subscribed they will be updated when the dataSubject.next() is fired off in the getData() method. Let me know if that doesn't make sense. Essentially this becomes an rxjs data store, think of it as a lightweight state along the lines of redux/ngrx without all the overhead of actions, reducers, connectors, etc

Comment: `switchMap` https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html

Comment: @Budhead2004 am I not already doing that with 
    this.dataSubject.next(availableDevices);
?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to cancel a http call is to unsubscribe from the subscription.

```
const subscription: Subscription = this.http.post(...).subscribe(...);
subscription.unsubscribe();
```

Your `teardown` method is useful, and generally used as garbage collection and to cancel any pending rxjs observables. You would call it in a service/component/directive ngOnDestroy hook, so to make sure no observables remain in memory.

But if I remember correctly, angular handles http observables, so you don't need to handle them. Generally speaking you only need to take care of observables generated by yourself, like your `BehaviorSubject`.

Comment: "cancel any pending rxjs observables". 

I might have not be clearer in the OP - that's what I'm trying to do here. Cancel the pending observables when the user changes the page, but it's not quite working.

Am I wrong in thinking this is a concern? I know when the user changes the page, it's going to resolve in the background. It just seemed wrong for me to have these expensive calls continue when they're effectively being thrown out.

Comment: You technically have to manage a basic data store, your `BehaviorSubject`. You are right that it is a concern. Your http calls will not cancel on page changes on their own, in this implementation. You have to add some logic that is watching page changes, and based on that need to cancel your http calls like I showed you.
I have a gist for navigation history. I think you can use that logic in your case too.

Check it here: https://gist.github.com/bgolyoo/206b83d4227c84dea6610a6765edee86

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I think the bigger problem I didn't mention is the fact that I'm getting excessive http calls during page load and only a few will cancel. 

Once the page is loaded and it's making the single HTTP call per action like it should, it is successfully canceled. 

I guess I was trying to cheat it and just hope cancelling would cancel *all of them*, but honestly at this point I should just investigate why I'm getting so many excessive calls. (Hence my musings on share and switchMap).

Answer (score 1):

I solved that using Promises (async functions) with AbortSignal / AbortController, because in my case the http request was not cancelled although the subject was cancelled. Maybe I made a mistake or it would work now. However, Promises with AbortController do the job too.

See [here](https://medium.com/@bramus/cancel-a-javascript-promise-with-abortcontroller-3540cbbda0a9) how to use AbortController. However, there might be a problem with browser compatibillity when using AbortController.

You can also convert observables into promises with .toPromise() so that should not be an issue.

Comment: This seems promising, though now I'm starting to question if my concern is even warranted haha.

Comment: That depends on the circumstances. In our app the user could go back and forth causing a second (but not equal) long runnig http request that was then really slow because of the first one still runnig. So your concern could be valid.

Comment: A good suggestion, but after looking into it, it's a bit too heavy handed when I can just use the unsubscribe in my teardown method.

Comment: Agreed, but when I tried to unsubscribe I could actually see in Chrome dev tools under network that the http request was still pending, although it was unsubscribed. Maybe I made a mistake there. Can you check in your app and let me know?

Comment: Take what I say with a grain of salt -- but for most basic HTTP requests, I am fine using a pipe operator of takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$). Where in my ngDestroy() I say this.unsubscribe$.next() (to flush out the call), and this.unsubscribe$.complete (to close the stream). 

My scenario mentioned above is a little different because I have an inner observable, so I do a combination of unsubscribing from the inner as well as using a takeUntil() -- when I switch pages, I do see it cancel in the dev console.

The larger issue I have is is having multiple XHR calls in the first place.